# Asp.net GridView does not show any data, just empty rows

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Why I get just empty rows without any data ?

---

EDIT:

Now I see my data thanks to Phil.
I just want to know two more little things:

- what is the `DataKeyNames` ?
- how would i get this data using LINQ ?

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridProcesses" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
EnableModelValidation="True" Width="400px" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CPU" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="RAM" />
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" SelectText="Kill" ShowSelectButton="True">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px" />
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code behind

```
public partial class OsControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private List<string> getTestData()
    {
        List<string> tData = new List<string>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tData.Add("proc" + i + "_" + rand.Next(100) + "_" + rand.Next(100));
        }

        return tData;
    }

    protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtProcesses = new DataTable();
        dtProcesses.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtProcesses.Columns.Add("CPU", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dtProcesses.Columns.Add("RAM", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dtProcesses.Columns.Add("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));

        int id = 0;
        foreach (string line in getTestData())
        {
            string[] items = line.Split('_');
            DataRow row = dtProcesses.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = items[0];
            row["CPU"] = int.Parse(items[1]);
            row["RAM"] = int.Parse(items[1]);
            row["ID"] = id++;
            dtProcesses.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        gridProcesses.DataSource = dtProcesses;
        gridProcesses.DataBind();
    }
}-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you specify not just the header text but also the data field:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
```

Comment: Great, it works! I added some more questions in my original post if you coul help me with them.

Comment: @Primoz - BTW, you might consider changing `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` to `typeof(string)`.  Is cleaner and adds the benefits of compile-time "typo" checking that you don't get with hard coded strings.

Comment: You missed `DataField="Name"` in ` <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" />`. It should be `<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />` (It is actually in the Phil Hunt's answer).

Comment: @Phil Hunt - He forgot to specify `DataField`.

Comment: @a1ex07 - I'm not following your comments on my answer.  Primoz's original question was why he was not seeing data (it was due to the absence of `DataField="Name"`).  My answer addressed that, and Primoz confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Responses to updated questions:

**What is `DataKeyNames`?**

This property gets or sets the primary key fields for items displayed in the GridView:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

**How would i get this data using LINQ?**

If using LINQ, you likely are thinking of LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework).  Describing EF in detail is a bit large for the scope of an answer, but this should get you started with databinding to EF:

http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/asp-net-databinding-with-linq-to-entities/

Comment: I added screenshoot for what i ment with LINQ.